# Access external json file with jquery and AJAX in DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, datatables

I want to be able to load a json file directly from the website:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        ajax:{
            url: 'https://secure.bixi.com/data/stations.json',
            dataSrc: 'stations'
        },
        columns: [
        { data: 'n' },
        { data: 's' },
        { data: 'ba' },
        { data: 'da' },
        { 
            data: 'b' ,
            render: function(d) {
                return d ? 'Oui' : 'Non';
            }
        },
        { 
            data: 'su',
            render: function(d) {
                return d ? 'Oui' : 'Non';
            }
        }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

The code above doesnt work.

When I save the URL locally and change the url property by my local file, it works.

Thanks

---

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3bqDX.png) is the console log that I get:

> Failed to load https://secure.bixi.com/data/stations.json?_=1508040566454: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '(my web server e.g. 127.0.0.1:8887)' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.

Seems like a cross origin error, like you said.

I'm a newbie to this, didn't think to look at the log.
Do you know a good tutorial on this?

Thanks for the quick answer btw.

Comment: what error do you have? this is probably a cross origin request error

Comment: Check your console log if you are receiving any error when you use an external link like `https://secure.bixi.com/data/stations.json`.

Comment: This is the console log that I get:

`Failed to load https://secure.bixi.com/data/stations.json?_=1508040566454: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '(my web server e.g. 127.0.0.1:8887)' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
`

Seems like a cross origin error, like you said.

I'm a newbie to this, didn't think to look at the log. Do you know a good tutorial on this?

Thanks for the quick answer btw.